# spring transaction management Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW not working

Tags: spring, transactions, required, propagation, requires

My Service Class.

```
@Service
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class DeviceServiceImpl{

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void blockAllDevices(){

    createSmsDeviceBlock();

}


public void createSmsDeviceBlock(){

    addToLogTables();

    smsService.sendSms();
}


@Transactional(readOnly = false,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addToLogTables(){
         try {
          //save object with DAO methods...
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new ServiceException(ServiceException.PROCESSING_FAILED, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
}
```

}

From my controller , service method blockAllDevices() getting called.
addToLogTables() method is marked as Propergation.REQUIRED_NEW, but the problem is with the addToLogTables() method new transaction not getting created and existing transaction is using.

The thing i want to do is, the transaction on addToLogTables() method should be commit before execute smsService.sendSms() method.

My problem here, if transaction failed to commit , on method addToLogTables() method, it should not execute smsService.sendSms() method.

Answer (score 11):

That's not a `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` issue. It's an issue with how `@Transactional` proxying works.

When Spring proxies your bean that's annotated with `@Transactional`, it basically wraps it in a proxy object and delegates to it after opening the transaction. When the delegated call returns, the proxy either commits or rolls back the transaction.

For example, your bean is

```
@Autowired
private DeviceServiceImpl deviceService;
```

Spring is actually going to inject a wrapper proxy.

So when you do

```
deviceService.blockAllDevices();
```

you are invoking the method on the proxy which has the transactional behavior. However, in `blockAllDevices()`, you are doing

```
createSmsDeviceBlock();
```

which is actually

```
this.createSmsDeviceBlock();
```

where `this` is referring to the actual object, not the proxy, so there is no transactional behavior.

This is further explained in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

You'll have to rework your design.

Comment: I can understand this, but are there any alternatives to do this...?
That is create new transaction within same..

Comment: You'll have to make the calls from outside or redactor so that the transactional methods are on some other bean that you inject into this one.

Comment: You can use AspectJ-based transaction management with load-time or compile-time weaving and spring-aspects, which allows you to have transactional self-calls, private transactional methods etc. Have a look at the Spring documentation for more info.